# How to modify the SignalR Hub URL

Tags: signalr

I would like to use a different base hub URL than `~/signalr/hubs`. How to modify this url, for example to `~/api/hubs`?

Second question, may I use a different url for a different sets of hubs? For example:

```
~/api/chat/hubs  
~/api/email/hubs
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ran across this, possible now with 0.5+:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs("~/api");
```

Answer (score 3):

1. No you may not, it's hardcoded in the source.
2. No the proxy generated is for all hubs.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it will be possible in a next version:).

Comment: I have a complex web application which I'm rewriting to be more RIA. This application contains a lot of disjunction sub set of pages (areas in MVC) and I would like to have different hub for each of this set. However, now I’m planning to use PersistentConnection (from different reason than above discussed). Thx

Answer (score 2):

Well this question is old (4 years? *wtf.. I always thought web sockets was kinda new*).

**... Well they(*Microsoft*) have new descriptive well written documentation on their [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server) now**

This could be a link only answer but if you are in a hurry.... On the server side at the startup or owin app config have somthing like this...

```
app.MapSignalR("/newCoolUrl", new HubConfiguration());
```

Ehhh sure you need to replace everything "/signalr" on whichever clients you are using to "/newCoolUrl" example

```
var connection = $.hubConnection("/newCoolUrl", { useDefaultPath: false });
```